# Add an existing node as a translation to another node

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am migrating contents from a multilingual website. I'm using Feed modules to import all the nodes so, in the end, I have multiple nodes that are in English and multiple nodes that are in French. Then, i wrote a DRUSH command where I have a CSV file that contains URL Alias of both slug of English and French. I can then process that info and get the node ID of both related Node.

But I just can't see how I can't tell drupal to attach an existing node (FR) as a translation of another node (EN). Does anyone has ever wanted to do something similar?

Thanks!